# Define relationship with a field?

Tags: 7, views

Is it possible to create a relationship based on a field?

In a field settings, I want to set the Relationship to be referencing another field. Does this make sense? I want to turn a field into a relationship.

An example: An integer field is meant to contain version id numbers. So have a relationship from the integer field to the node_revision table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [hook_views_data_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data_alter/7), I came up with code along the lines of the following which seems to work for my example in the question:

```
$data['field_data_FIELDNAME']['dummy_name'] = array(
  'title' => t('Map field to other db column'),
  'group' => t('Custom mapping'),
  'relationship' => array(
    'base' => 'node_revision',
    'base field' => 'vid',
    'field' => 'FIELDNAME_value',
    'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
    'label' => t('Map field to db column'),
    'title' => t('Field to db map'),
  ),
);
```